# GLSL Shader Breaks Upon Adding Simple Statement

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a simple, working vertex shader. In full:

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

in vec4 in_pos;

out vec4 color;

main(void) {
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * in_pos;
    color = vec4(0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
}
```

This works perfectly as expected.

I am trying to add normals and have opted to use multiple VBOs rather than interleaving. So I have added a second attribute as follows;

```
glBindAttribLocation(shaderProgramID, 1, "in_normal");
```

Enabled it;

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

And written data to it:

```
int nVBO = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Each of these three stages precisely mirrors my code for the `in_pos` attribute, which appears to work perfectly, so I assume all of the above is ok?

At this stage, if I compile and run, it works exactly as before. The problem appears when I try to edit the shader file.

I add the new `in` attribute; `in vec4 in_normal;`, it still compiles and runs with no changes to the render.

As soon as I add *any* reference to `in_normal` in the `main()` body (such as `vec4 n = in_normal;`), the program will have a completely black render. The shader reports that it compiled fine, and `glGetError()` is empty throughout the program.

Why is such a simple change breaking the pipeline? Particularly when it has no effect on the `color` variable, and still compiles without error.

Finally for completeness, the broken version of the shader:

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

in vec4 in_pos;
in vec4 in_normal;

out vec4 color;

main(void) {
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * in_pos;
    vec4 n = in_normal;
    color = vec4(0.6, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: As a side note (though unrelated to the problem), you should rather take the normal as a `vec3`, since it's definitely a vector and it would actually be rather counter-intuitive to get its `w` coordinate set `1` (which the GL automatically does when just uploading 3-vectors), since vectors need a `w` of `0` (and if you don't want to set that explicitly by uploading 4-component normals, which would be even more unintuitive, then taking it as `vec3` is the best option).

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29672/in-out-keywords-in-glsl 
Maybe the problem is your #version ?

Comment: @FullFrontalNudity These are the modern non-deprecated versions of `attribute` and have been introduced long before GLSL `1.50` (the version used by the OP).

Comment: @ChristianRau thanks, I still have a little confusion over vec4 usage. I know that in_pos needs to be vec4 for the calculation of gl_Position, but I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Oh wow, I fixed it. Standby for self-answer. Not sure I fully understand it, so a little explanation would be awesome.

Comment: @lynks Elaborating on why the transformation pipeline actually works on 4-vectors would be too long and theoretical for a comment, but it is true that the position attribute is best taken as `vec4` (it can still be uploaded with 3-vectors in which case GL will automatically set `w` to `1`, which is correct for points but not for vectors like normals).

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get the pipeline working again, by moving the `glLinkProgram()` statement to *after* the calls to `glBindAttribLocation()`.

This went unnoticed due to attribute 0 working by default (I assume...)

Comment: And this is exactly the expected behaviour. `glBindAttribLocation` only takes effect at the next linking. If an attribute hasn't been bound explicitly, then `glLinkProgram` will assign an index itself, which can be retrieved with `glGetAttribLocation`. For the 1-attribute version this just happened to be 0, but for the other version it probably assigned something else (maybe switched the order or whatever).

Comment: FYI the reason why this worked before actually using the new attribute inside the `main` function is, that the GLSL compiler is allowed and encouraged to optimize away any unused attributes and uniforms, so this version was just equivalent to the position-only-shader.

Comment: And last but not least, since GLSL 3.30 (which is the version belonging to OpenGL 3.3 and thus the one after your 1.50 belonging to OpenGL 3.2) it is even easier without the need for an API call at all: `layout(location=0) in vec4 position; layout(location=1) in vec3 normal;`.

Comment: @ChristianRau ahh, interesting. Thanks for all your pointers.